# Why is my scroll bar doing the opposite of what I want?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dashboard

Alright, so here's what I'm trying to do. I have a dashboard with a list of items (Dashboard 1, Dashboard 2,..., etc.). I'm trying to make them each have a dropdown bar come down whenever I click on one of them. Here's what I got:

Here is a.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Database</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dashboard.css"/>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/general.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div class="logo"> 
                <a href="index.html"><img src="/images/whatever.png"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="container">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li><a class=selected href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dashboard 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dashboard 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dashboard 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dashboard 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                some content yay

                <div id="box">
                    <div class="box-top">News</div>
                    <div class="box-panel"> This is simple news lalal</div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is dashboard.css (note, styles.css isn't really important in this and is mainly meant for different pages, so I'm not including it):

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div#dbheader {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #010101;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.logo a {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

div#container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #171717;
    float: left;
}

.content {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 250px;
    background-color: #222;
    padding: 15px;
}

ul#nav li{

}


ul#nav li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #aaa;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-color: #111;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s;
    -o-transition: 0.2s;
     transition: 0.2s;
}

ul#nav li a:hover,
ul#nav li a:active{
    background-color:#030303;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 20px;
/*    margin-left: 5px;*/
}

ul#nav li a.selected {
    background-color: #030303;
    color: #fff;
}


div#box {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

div#box .box-top {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #000;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    background-color: #2980b9;
    font-weight: 300;
}

div#box .box-panel {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #999;
}
```

and finally, here's my general.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("ul#nav li a.selected").click(function(){
      $("ul#nav li").slideToggle('fast');

   });
});
```

What happens is that I want to click on the a.selected part of my sidebar menu, and then I want the sidebar I already have (just to see if it works) to slide down fast. What happens though is that when I click on a.selected (aka Dashboard 1), the whole sidebar retracts back into Dashboard 1 and the dashboard side bar just disappears. So it essentially did the opposite of what I wanted.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. What does "have a dropdown bar come down" mean? However, I can tell you why it is doing what it is doing. The `slideToggle` method shows or hides the element(s) on which it is applied. You are calling it on the selector "ul#nav li", which selects all of the list items, so they all get hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your intent correctly, this code should do the job:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul#nav li a.selected").click(function(){
    $("ul#nav li:not(:first-child)").slideToggle('fast');
  });
});
```